# How do I choose which monitor that my virtual console is on?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, multiple-monitors, virtual-console

I turn on virtual console and when I do, it uses my first monitor when I want it to use my second monitor. I don't know how to select which monitor it goes on, I have also tried to do primary monitor and it still doesn't work. If anyone knows how to fix it, please help. Thank you.